# Powershell create file on file server and open on desktop

Tags: powershell

I want to be able to create a file on a file server and then open this file on my PC right after the file creation. I have the following script (edited to hide confident info.)

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName FileServerComputer -ScriptBlock { 
$NewFile = "test.docx" 
$path = Join-Path E:\foo\bar\'test test'\ $NewFile  
New-Item $path -type file
if (Test-Path $path) {Invoke-Item $path}
} -Credential userName
```

This script creates the file on the file server successfully, but does not open the file anywhere. Ive tried removing the if statement and that didn't seem to be the problem.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Make sure that the value of `$path` actually exists, and that you have a program that can open the file as default.

Comment: The path does exist as file is created on that file location every time i run the script and files with a ".docx" extension open with word by default on my PC. @Nick

Comment: You're not getting any errors from it? If the path will be the same every time, you could just type out the path without the `invoke-item` and it would open it. You can use that to test as well. Is the folder really something like 'test test' with the space and quotes?

Comment: No errors, I removed 'invoke-item' and typed out the file path and still get the same behavior. 'test test' is just to show what some of the folders in the file path have spaces in them. @Nick

Answer (score 1):

Running what you have and assuming you actually have single quotes in the folder name, it fails because it's converting the single quotes in 'test test' to nothing. So if you add quotes around the whole path it will work

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName FileServerComputer -ScriptBlock { 
$NewFile = "test.docx" 
$path = Join-Path "E:\foo\bar\'test test'\" $NewFile  
New-Item $path -type file
if (Test-Path $path) {Invoke-Item $path}
} -Credential userName
```

Comment: There are many folders in the file path which have spaces in them. I don't get any errors with my script and the file is created just fine, but i just cant get the file to open.

Comment: And if you navigate to the file from your workstation, you can open it?

Comment: Yes i can navigate to the file from my workstation. In file explorer i have "\\FileServerComputer\" instead of "E:\" like i do in the scripts @Nick

Comment: You can't access a drive on a remote computer with just the letter. You'd need it to be `\\fileservercomputer\e$\folder1\folder2`

Comment: Did that fix your issue?

Comment: I can create the file, but still can't manage to open it from the same script. @Nick

Comment: Did you change it to the full path?

Comment: And why couldn't you change it to `Join-path \\fileserver\folder1\folder2\$newfile`?

Comment: Are you referring to when the script is being created or when it's being opened? @Nick

Comment: Do `$path = Join-Path \\fileserver\folder1\'folder2'\'folder3 with spaces'\ $NewFile `

Comment: Tried that and it still doesn't open the file. @Nick

Answer (score 0):

Not a very elegant solution as the`$NewFile`variable isn't being used to open the file, but at least the script creates and opens a file at once.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName FileServer -ScriptBlock { 
$NewFile = "Test.txt" 
$path = Join-Path E:\folder1\'folder2'\'folder3 with spaces'\ $NewFile  
New-Item $path -type file
} -Credential userName
Invoke-Item \\FileServer\folder1\'folder2'\'folder3 with spaces'\Test.txt
```

Can anyone help improve the efficiency of this script by showing how to use the`$NewFile`variable to open the file?